# How to add hyperlinkbuttons dynamically from c# codebehind to a stackpanel present in the listbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi i have a requirement i need your help for it:-

I have a set of phone numbers of type string separated by a comma , now i want to assign each phone number to hyperlink  and on  click of it will invoke the PhoneCallTask  and make a call to that particular phone number.

1) So , how to assign each phone number to a hyperlink(should we dynamically generate the hyperlink? in c# codebehind)

2)if so , how to dynamically generate hyperlink buttons  and add it to a stack panel present in a listbox ?

3)How would i know which Hyperlinkbutton is clicked?

4)All HyperlinkButton's would point to same hyperlink click event?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MainPage.xaml, add this inside the ContentPanel control:

```
<ListBox x:Name="PhoneNumbersList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding}" Click="PhoneNumberHyperlinkButton_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then, on the MainPage code behind, add this code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var phoneNumbers = new string[] { "9999999", "8888888", "7777777" };

    PhoneNumbersList.ItemsSource = phoneNumbers;
}

private void PhoneNumberHyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var phoneNumberHyperlinkButton = (HyperlinkButton)sender;

    var phoneNumber = (string)phoneNumberHyperlinkButton.Content;

    new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask()
    {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }.Show();
}
```

That's it!

Comment: first of all , Thanks a lot for the Reply you made it so simple. once again thanks, in case of any queries i will contact you again.

Comment: What should i do if i want to bind it  to a particluar stackpanel inside a listbox specfically? i tried it in this way :::-  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                                <HyperlinkButton FontFamily="Calibri" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" Content="{Binding PhoneNumbers}" Foreground="Blue" Width="300"  FontSize="26"></HyperlinkButton>                </StackPanel> but it doesnot work for me and it is not being displayed ?

Comment: i want to know how to bind it to you particular stackpanel inside a listbox instead of binding directly to a listbox ?

Comment: Don't know what you intend to do: if it's a list of items (like an array or List<>), you should bind it to a control that handles lists, not a control that handles one item, like a StackPanel... what is the purpose you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a parent listbox, inside the datatemplate of which I have multiple stackpanels. Inside one of the stack panels I need to show this list of phone numbers one below the other. So it means I have to nest one list box inside the other and so, I can't access the nested listbox in code behind directly. 

Also the binding is not working as you mentioned above whenever I nest the listboxes.

Comment: Ok, assuming you have a list of some class and in that class you have a property called `PhoneNumbers` with a list of numbers like mine, you should set the inner LisBox to `ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneNumbers}"`